# Windows Service does not start automatically after stopping Azure VM from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, virtual-machines

I'm facing a strange issue getting a Windows Service to automatically start when an Azure VM is stopped from Azure Portal and started again. The Windows Service in question is a .NET Core self contained app, published as a single self-extracting executable. The service is installed to start automatically. The VM image I'm using is Windows 10.

Following are the scenarios I've tried and which ones work or don't work.

- If I **restart** the VM from within the VM itself, then my service starts and runs as expected.
- If I **shutdown** the VM from within the VM itself, then my service starts and runs as expected.
- If I **stop** the VM from Azure Portal and start it again, then my service does not start and run as expected.

Looking in event logs the following is the error displayed:

```
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the <service name> service to connect.
```

If I increase the timeout in the registry as suggested [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/922918/a-service-does-not-start-and-events-7000-and-7011-are-logged-in-window) then the problem does go away.

Any idea what could cause the VM not to start the service in question after a stop and start? Could there be some resource contention taking place because the VM needs to carry out more tasks after a stop from the Azure portal?

Comment: Out of interest,.what VM type are you using?

Comment: Azure VMs, if that is what you meant by VM type? Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: I mean the series,.so like A series, Bs, D etc.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMoore, how can I find out the series from the VM or the portal?

Comment: On the main overview of a VM is should say ",Size", something like Standard_B1s

Comment: Thanks. The VM I have says `Standard_B4ms`

Comment: Ah blows my theory. I had wondered if you were using a burstable VM type - which you are in fact - with burstable you have a baseline performance and a credit system for usage, I was wondering if in some way you were exhausting credits at boot and so performance would slow down, causing the timeout. However while a b4ms is burstable, it's baseline performance is 90% so probably not low enough that it would cause such a dramatic problem. Is there some way in your app you can write some logs to debug when the process is started and when it reaches various stages of initialisation?

Comment: Thinking to understand if it's your process starting that is slowed by something.

Comment: I have put logs at the start of the `Main` method, and that never actually gets written, so it appears not even the `Main` method of my app is getting called.

Comment: One theory I had is if the self-extraction of the .NET core app is taking long, but I took that out of the equation and same issue occurs.